# laravel value passed to function won't get passed into Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I have a function in laravel for saving data into a database and for some reason, one of the variables will not be added to the database, specifically the id for the calendar. I have tried returning the variable before and after the database entry and it exists at both times, it just won't get added. Here is what I have so far:

```
class SetupPhotoshoot{

public function createListing(Request $request){

$calendarAdd = $this->addToCalendar($request);

$addtoDB = $this->addToDB($request, $calendarAdd['id']);

return $addtoDB;

  }
protected function addToDB($request, $calendarID){

     //Some code here

     return $calendarID;  //This is to see if the id exists inside the function, which it does.

    $newSchedule = new Schedule;

     $addtoDB = $newSchedule->create({
     //Add a bunch of fields
     'services_id' => $request->Package,
     'appt_time' => $request->DateTime,
     'total' => $request->total,
     'calendar_id' => $calendarID //This is where I want the id to be added, but it isn't working.
});

     return $calendarID;  //I tried returning after adding to DB to see if it somehow got lost between before adding to DB and after, but it still returned.

//NOTE: the two individual returns were NOT used at the same time. I commented out one to test if the other returned, so it IS NOT because I used return multiple times.

  }

}
```

All other data is added to the database properly, except the `calendar_id.`The specific error it says is "General error: 1364 Field 'calendar_id' doesn't have a default value." When I allowed null values, it only adds "null" as the value in the database. Here is what it looks like in the database (this is MYSQL):

```
Name: calendar_id

Type: varchar(191)  utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Null: Yes

Default: None
```

Comment: How does the schedule.create() look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'calendar_id' doesn't have a default value

`$calendarID` is not being passed, maybe it is null, use `dd($calendarID)` to make sure it is set.

`create()` is also a static method, so do not create an instance of `Schedule`
as you can call it statically `Schedule::create($data)`.

On your model, make sure `calendar_id` is part of your fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = [
     'services_id',
     'appt_time',
     'total',
     'calendar_id'
];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It was actually because I forgot to add it to $fillable, which is obvious now. I think I didn't call it as a static method before because I was having issues and I was just debuging and forgot to change it back, but I did that as well. Thanks again.